# Delete Excel Sheet Rows using SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need to delete the excel rows if two column value matches. I am using below code for this `.GSTIN` and `GSTIN/ UIN` of Recipient is the name of column. If both the column values are equal I have to delete those rows. I am writing this as excel as a database. Could anyone please help me with the missing syntax.

```
strSQL = ""
strSQL = "Delete [Sheet$] SET"
strSQL = strSQL + " Where [GSTIN] = [GSTIN/ UIN of Recipient]"
```

Comment: You can't delete rows using ADO.

Comment: any other way of deleting the rows?